# Select oldest column for grouped spark dataframe

Tags: dataframe, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

Given a dataframe (df) with the following columns:

```
id,
created_date,
name
```

I need to ensure that all rows with the same name have the same id. I can create a mapping from old id to new id (selected at 'random' using max).

```
df.groupBy('name')\
  .agg(
    func.max('id').alias('new_id'),                         
    func.collect_set(id).alias('grouped_ids'))\
  .filter(func.size('grouped_ids') > 1)\                
  .select(func.explode("grouped_ids").alias('old_id'), "new_id")\
  .filter("new_id != old_id")
```

I can the leftouter join this to the original df (on id = old_id) and swap the ids if there is a new_id available.

However, I need to ensure that the new_id selected is the one with the oldest created_date in the dataframe (rather than just selecting the max).

How best to go about this?

e.g. Given the data

```
id, created_date, name
---
17a, 2019-01-05, Jeff
17a, 2019-01-03, Jeremy
d21, 2019-01-04, Jeremy
u45, 2019-01-04, Jeremy
d21, 2019-01-02, Scott
x22, 2019-01-01, Julian
```

Rows 2, 3 and 4 group on Jeremy so should have the same id. The oldest id in the dataframe for the grouped ids is d21 as on row 5 the created_date is 2019-01-02, so that should be selected and applied to all rows in the dataframe with the other grouped ids, and we end up with:

```
id, created_date, name
---
d21, 2019-01-05, Jeff
d21, 2019-01-03, Jeremy
d21, 2019-01-04, Jeremy
d21, 2019-01-04, Jeremy
d21, 2019-01-02, Scott
x22, 2019-01-01, Julian
```

**UPDATE:**
@Charles Du - Cheers, I tried your code but it didn't work out, the oldest id was selected from the grouped names, not the df as a whole and the new_id was not applied throughout the df.

```
Result:
0 = {Row} Row(name='Scott', created_date='2019-01-02', new_ID='d21', id='d21', created_date='2019-01-02')
1 = {Row} Row(name='Julian', created_date='2019-01-01', new_ID='x22', id='x22', created_date='2019-01-01')
2 = {Row} Row(name='Jeremy', created_date='2019-01-03', new_ID='17a', id='17a', created_date='2019-01-03')
3 = {Row} Row(name='Jeremy', created_date='2019-01-03', new_ID='17a', id='d21', created_date='2019-01-04')
4 = {Row} Row(name='Jeremy', created_date='2019-01-03', new_ID='17a', id='u45', created_date='2019-01-04')
5 = {Row} Row(name='Jeff', created_date='2019-01-05', new_ID='17a', id='17a', created_date='2019-01-05')
```

Answer (score 0):

My spitball here

```py
from pyspark.sql import functions as F

new_df = df.groupBy('name').agg(F.min('date'))

new_df = new_df.join(df, on=['name', 'date'], how='inner')

# This should give you a df with a single record for each name with the oldest ID.

new_df = new_df.withColumnRenamed('id', 'new_ID')

#you'll need to decide on a naming convention for your date column since you'll have two if you don't rename

res = new_df.join(df, on='name', how='inner)
```

that should match up your id with the oldest date.

Comment: But how come the ids will be replaced by the oldest id in the column? Which part of your code does that ?

Comment: The join on date and name will give you the oldest id.

Comment: Then the join back to the original dafaframe on name only will give you the new IDs matched up to the old ID

Comment: You got it wrong I guess. He wants all the ids to be replaced by the old id, not the only matching ones.

Comment: Please explain to me how I got it wrong. The new_df I create generates a table with the names as a primary key and the oldest date and its corresponding id. If you inner join that back to the original table. You'll get the oldest id matching to each name

Comment: @Breandan, I might have misunderstood your original question. Looking back at it, how does Jeff's id get changed to d21?

Comment: Jeff is linked to a Jeremy on id so if Jeremy changes id, then Jeff must do so too i.e. A Jeremy has the id 17a (same as Jeff), since this Jeremy's id is changing to d21, all other rows with id 17a also need to change to the new id.

Comment: @Breandan, can a name only be linked to one other name via id? Or can there be multiple links?

Comment: There can be multiple